# Binding Sails.js route to model blueprint action via request body

Tags: node.js, routes, sails.js

I'm using [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/) v0.11.1. 
In my routes.js file I have this route written:

```
'POST /user' : {
    model:     'user',
    blueprint: 'create'
},
```

I'm sending a POST request (via [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)) to `/user` with this in the body:

```
{
    userName  : "firstUser",
    password  : "secretPwd5779", 
    firstName : "William",
    lastName  : "Askey"
}
```

but I'm getting this response:

```
{
    "error": "E_VALIDATION",
    "status": 400,
    "summary": "4 attributes are invalid",
    "model": "User",
    "invalidAttributes": {
        "userName": [
            {
                "rule": "string",
                "message": "`undefined` should be a string (instead of \"null\", which is a object)"
            },
            {
                "rule": "required",
                "message": "\"required\" validation rule failed for input: null"
            }
        ],
        "password": [
            {
                "rule": "string",
                "message": "`undefined` should be a string (instead of \"null\", which is a object)"
            },
            {
                "rule": "required",
                "message": "\"required\" validation rule failed for input: null"
            }
        ],
        "firstName": [
            {
                "rule": "string",
                "message": "`undefined` should be a string (instead of \"null\", which is a object)"
            },
            {
                "rule": "required",
                "message": "\"required\" validation rule failed for input: null"
            }
        ],
        "lastName": [
            {
                "rule": "string",
                "message": "`undefined` should be a string (instead of \"null\", which is a object)"
            },
            {
                "rule": "required",
                "message": "\"required\" validation rule failed for input: null"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

According to the [Sails.js documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/routes/custom-routes#?blueprint-target-syntax) I've written the route correctly.

Making this request via URL parameters (i.e. making the request to `/user?userName=firstUser&password=secretPwd5779&firstName=William&lastName=Askey` works just fine. How can I get this to work without sending data via URL parameters?

Comment: can You show us the page (form), javascript where You posting data?

Comment: I'm using the REST client postman (https://www.getpostman.com) to make this request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@num8er's answer was insightful for a me (as a novice sailsjs/node programmer) but my issue was actually caused by rogue [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io) instances.

The requests I was making was being sent to a rogue instance where the routes/changes I've written did not reflect in the code. Hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 2):

Standard way:

This is Your form:

```
<form class="ajax" method="post" action="/user">
<input name="userName">
<input name="password">
<input name="firstName">
<input name="lastName">
<button type="submit">CREATE</button>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

and this is frontend js part (jquery is required):

```
$(function(){
  $('form.ajax').on('submit', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var method = $(this).attr('method');
      var url = $(this).attr('action');
      var data = $(this).serializeArray();

      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: method,
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
          $('#result').html(JSON.stringify(response));
        },
        error: function() {
         alert('Error! Try again later.');
        }
      });
  });
});
```

But You're sending json body, so have to enable middleware that will convert json body to request.body.
it's called body-parser. see screenshot: http://joxi.ru/752aJJbhj45DA0

Comment: I'm actually not making a request via a form but rather a REST client

Comment: Read very very last sentences

Comment: hmm, I've uncommented that line and still nothing. This is what my file looks like: https://infinit.io/_/nxNmm9w and the response I'm getting from the server: `Cannot GET /user/create`

Comment: I'm happy to help, but need to inspect, debug. Add me to Skype: anarjafarov I'll help You

Comment: Thanks @num8er! I'll add you in an hour or two.